# Is there a way to join FLA files without copying frames?

Tags: actionscript-3, flash

I have two FLA files and i want to join them together. Is there a way to do this without copying frames? Reason why i'm doing this is to prevent making one huge FLA file that is hard to edit thanks.

Comment: You can load and join SWFs at runtime, you know.

Comment: You want to join two FLA's without making one huge FLA... sorry but that doesn't make sense.